# How can I validate the entire request received within an array with the same validation rule?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to validate all requests received via $ request () -> all (). They must be all because the amount received can vary since I have the inputs within a foreach that can vary their amount.

so I need to validate everything with the validation rules 'string' and 'required'

```
@foreach ($questions as $index => $question)
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="form-group row">
     <div class="col-md-4 mt-2">
         <label for="form-control-label" class="d-flex justify-content-end"> 
           <b{{$question>description }}</b></label>
     </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <input type="text" name="sectionTime{{ $index }}" class="form-control">
                <div class="text-center"> 
                    {!! $errors->first('sectionTime'.$index, '<strong class="text-danger">:message</strong>') !!}
                </div>
            </div>
      </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

```
$req = $request->all();
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
             $req => ['required', 'string']
        ]);
```

I tried to do it this way but it doesn't work.
is there any way i can do it?

Comment: try `'*' => ['required','string']` instead of `$req => ['required', 'string']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You better set the input type to an array (using the index too)

```
<input type="text" name="sectionTime[{{ $index }}]" class="form-control">
```

Then the validation will use the format for [nested array input](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#validating-nested-array-input)

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'sectionTime.*' => 'required|string'
]);
```

After that, you can access the inputs as such

```
$sectionTime = $request->input('sectionTime');
//section one
$sectionTime['index_one']; // or $sectionTime[1]... use the same indexes as the on you set in the html
```